# How to check window.innerWidth in React/Gatsby before the website will render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, gatsby

On the website I create in Gatsby I would like to check the size of the DOM window.innerWidth before it will be first rendered. I would like to use a conditional check of innerWidth to decide how the website should be rendered: as desktop or mobile version.
A simple fix for that would be to check the width of the window before creating react component and use the true/false value further in the code. It works in development version but...
The case is that in production version when I do *gatsby build*, I get an error in console:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.872s

 ERROR #95312 

"window" is not available during server-side rendering.

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

> 30 |     const sizeOfWindow = window.innerWidth;
```

I tried already to use **componentWillMount** which works fine but it is deprecated and marked as unsafe.
If I check the window.innerWidth in componentDidMount doesn't render properly.

My code:

```
interface IndexPageState {
  isDesktop: boolean;
  windowWidth: number;
}

class IndexPage extends React.Component<any, IndexPageState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      windowWidth: 0,
      isDesktop: true,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(): void {
    this.onResize();
  }

  onResize = () => {
    if (!(this.state.windowWidth >= 769)) {
      this.setState({ isDesktop: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isDesktop: true });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
    if (!(this.state.windowWidth >= 769)) {
      this.setState({ isDesktop: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isDesktop: true });
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  };

  render() {
    const { isDesktop, windowWidth } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <SEO title="Home" />
        <div className={styles.App}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gatsby, you must check for the availability of the browser global variables like `document` or `window`, since at the time your code is compiling and asking for those variables, they may not be declared/available yet.

From the [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/):

> Some of your code references “browser globals” like `window` or
> `document`. If this is your problem you should see an error above like
> “window is not defined”. To fix this, find the offending code and
> either a) check before calling the code if window is defined so the
> code doesn’t run while Gatsby is building (see code sample below) or
> b) if the code is in the render function of a React.js component, move
> that code into a [`componentDidMount` lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) or into a [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect),
> which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser

So, every time you check for the `window`, you must add:

```
    if(typeof window !== undefined){
     //your stuff
    }
```

Applied to your code:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    if(typeof window !== undefined){
      this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
      if (!(this.state.windowWidth >= 769)) {
        this.setState({ isDesktop: false });
      } else {
        this.setState({ isDesktop: true });
      }
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    }
  };


  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    if(typeof window !== undefined){
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    }

   onResize = () => {
    if(typeof window !== undefined){ 
       if (!(this.state.windowWidth >= 769)) {
         this.setState({ isDesktop: false });
       } else {
       this.setState({ isDesktop: true });
       }
     }
   };
};
```

Of course, the code above should be refactored to avoid the repetition of the condition, by adding the `window` condition before the event is triggered for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap getting the window width in the callback, so add function `getWindowWidth` where you will return the actual window width.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute `window.innerWidth` after checking the `window` is defined first in this way.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
    }
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can [check this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-code-classlanguage-textwindowcode-is-defined) as well that how to check if `window` is defined.